# Adding Bower to Gulp/Nodemon/Browsersync/Angular configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp, bower

Almost feels like I'm being greedy with all these dependancies at the moment, but I'd love to add Bower into my current workflow.

My AngularJS app is built on a Node/Express server, with Browsersync as well. I use `Gulp` to run it all. Here's my current `Gulpfile` (with comments that I've kept in for my own learning):

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var bower = require('gulp-bower');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

var BROWSER_SYNC_RELOAD_DELAY = 500;

gulp.task('less', function() {
    gulp.src('./public/css/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function(cb) {
    var called = false;
    return nodemon({

            script: 'app-local.js',

            watch: ['app-local.js', 'routes/**.js', 'config/*.js', 'app/**/*.js']
        })
        .on('start', function onStart() {
            if (!called) {
                cb();
            }
            called = true;
        })
        .on('restart', function onRestart() {
            setTimeout(function reload() {
                browserSync.reload({
                    stream: false //
                });
            }, BROWSER_SYNC_RELOAD_DELAY);
        });
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./public/css/*.less', ['less']);
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon', 'less', 'watch'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        files: ['public/**/*.*', 'views/**/*.jade'],
        proxy: 'https://localhost:8080',
        port: 4000,
        browser: ['google-chrome']
    });
});


gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync']);
```

Nodemon is processing my `JADE` templates into HTML and doing most of the heaving lifting here.

Currently I have my `.js` dependancies living in `/public/js/vendor/` and they're hard-coded into my `/views/index.jade` view, like so:

```
  script(src='/js/vendor/papa-parse.js')
  script(src='/js/vendor/d3.js')
  script(src='/js/vendor/nvd3.js')  
  script(src='/js/vendor/angular.js')
  script(src='/js/vendor/ngd3-angular.js')
  script(src='/js/vendor/angular-animate.js')
  script(src='/js/vendor/angular-aria.js')
  script(src='/js/vendor/angular-messages.js')
  script(src='/js/vendor/angular-material.js')
  script(src='/js/vendor/angular-route.js')
```

I'd like to replace these with a simple:

```
 // bower:js
 // endbower
```

and have Gulp do the rest of the work. I've tried:

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function() {
    var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
    gulp.src(mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe(wiredep())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/views/index.jade'));
});
```

then adding the `wiredep` task before `nodemon` runs - `gulp.task('browser-sync', ['wiredep', 'nodemon', 'less', 'watch'])`, but this doesn't work at all.

What's the best way to get all of this working smoothly together?

Comment: Have you tried running it as an individual task? does it work in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Bower is good for managing dependencies and their versions. However if you want to only have to include one dependency in your template, then perhaps something that you're already using would be the answer... Gulp.

I might not be understanding the question correctly, but it sounds like you only want to include one dependency and have that updated with the other dependencies when you add them. In which case you could use gulps concat function.

```
gulp.task('dependecies',function(){
    return gulp.src(['bower_components/**/*.js','!bower_components/**/*.min.js'])
    .pipe(concat('dependencies.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js/vendor'));
});
```

This would then list concatenate all of your bower vendor dependencies into one file, then you only need to include the one script into your template. Also if you updated your dependencies, then you simply run the dependencies task again to regenerate the dependencies.js file.

And if you didn't want to add bower then you wouldn't have to, just change the above code to your current dependencies directory.

Not sure if this helps, but here's hoping.

Comment: Ah, this is a novel solution and I like it. However, wouldn't this load EVERYTHING in bower's components? For example, if a director has `angular.js` and `angular.min.js` it would add both...this is why I was trying to use `mainBowerFiles`, but I could be ENTIRELY wrong in understanding how it all works (the explanation docs for `mainBowerFiles` are nonexistant)

Comment: You are correct, I've updated my answer with the fix to this issue, this will ensure the minified versions are not included

Comment: And I suppose I'd need a different task to accommodate when CSS files are included? (e.g. angular-material, Bootstrap etc)

Comment: Yes you would need a separate task for doing the CSS. Then if you had a build task you could have both of these tasks called so you'd only need one task to call.

Comment: I accepted the answer perhaps a bit prematurely. This is now throwing me an error of: "Unexpected reserved word" of `import`. Blindly grabbing all `.js` files won't work because there are several other `.js` files within a bower module that will break code if concatted into a main `vendor.js` file.